# Disable tap on Windows phone 8 - html5 mobile application

Tags: html, css, windows-phone-8

How to disable tap on few pages in Windows phone 8?

The pages of the applications are designed and developed using HTML5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code worked for me. Need to add the below CSS property for the pages to disable touch.

```
-ms-touch-action:none
```